# How to find the positive solution to $\frac{x^d}{d} = 2^x$?

Tags: approximation

I asked Wolfram, and it gave me [a complicated answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%5Ed%2Fd%20%3D%202%5Ex) involving the ProductLog function $W$.  Is there a simpler, approximate answer?

Comment: Probably not - the $W$ function is there precisely  because equations like this usually can't be solved without it,

Comment: It's worth noting, though, that $0.6931471...=\ln 2$ and $1.4427=\frac{1}{\ln 2}$.

Comment: If you want to solve this equation over a certain range of values for $d$, perhaps you can use a Taylor series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not possible without the $W$-function.

Here's how to get Wolfram's answer:

Writing $2^x=e^{x\log 2}$ taking the $d$th root, and doing some re-arranging, and you get:

$$xe^{-x\log 2/d} = d^{1/d}$$

Multiplying both sides by $-\frac{\log 2}d$ and letting $y=-\frac{x\log 2}d$ you get:

$$ye^y = -\frac{d^{1/d}\log 2}{d}$$

That means:

$$y=W\left(-\frac{d^{1/d}\log 2}{d}\right)$$

or:

$$x=\frac{-d}{\log 2}W\left(-\frac{d^{1/d}\log 2}{d}\right)$$

Since we are dealing with negative values, $W(u)$ has two real values for $-1/e<u<0$, called $W_0(u)$ and $W_{-1}(u)$.  For $u$ small, we have that $W_0(u)=u-u^2+O(u^3)$. so we get:

$$\begin{align}x &= d^{1/d} +\frac{\log 2}{d^{1-2/d}} + O\left(\frac{1}{d^{2}}\right)
\end{align}$$

The asymptotic for $W_{-1}(u)$ are more complicated, unfortunately, [but they might be useful.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions)

Comment: What is W here? Actually I don't know higher maths so please help me out

Comment: $W(x)$ is defined as the solution $w$ of $we^w=x$. It is called the Lambert $W$-function, or the product logarithm function. @sgrmshrsm7 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: Wait... is the result negative? I was sure there must be a positive answer. For every $d$, $2^x$ is asymptotically larger than $x^d/d$, so the graph of $2^x$ must at some point (for some positive value of $x$) cross the graph of $x^d/d$. For example, this graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xxb2yjrqbc shows that, for $d=5$, the crossing point is at $x=18.8$. Is there an approximation to this positive solution?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Yep, I dropped a sign. I forgot the minus sign inside the $W$ call. Fixed

Comment: Is there an approximation that holds at least asymptotically, using  big-$O$ notation?

Comment: Don't know. Presumably, you mean for large $d$?